# I just can't destroy a session in php

Tags: php

When I logout by destroying the session and start another one it always shows me the first session info I started $_SESSION['username'];

What I mean here is that :
I started a session the first time I logged with this username --> AAAAAA
And destroyed the session using the file logout.php which contains this code :

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location: login.php");
```

and login with another username ---> BBBBBB
and it always shows me the first username I logged in with---> AAAAAA

Where is the problem here

Here is the code (login.php)

```
<?php
        session_start();
        require_once "config/db.php";
        if(isset($_POST['login'])){     
        $username       = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));
        $password       = trim(mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']))); 
        $query          = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ")  or die(mysql_error());
         $rows           = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($rows == 1){

            while($info = mysql_fetch_object($query)){            
                $dbusername = $info->username;
                $dbpassword = $info->password;
            }

            if($dbusername == $username && $dbpassword == $password){                   
                header("Location: index.php");         
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
            }       

        }else{

        }
    }
?>
```

the index.php :

```
  <?php session_start();?>
  <h3><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h3>
```

Comment: Are you setting a session after sending headers? It will never be updated.Replace those rows and it should work.Another thing, according to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php , consider deleting also the cookie of the session_id

Comment: Only hashing a password with MD5 is not enough. Use bcrypt instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [docs](http://php.net/session_destroy):

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

[Example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php):

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Comment: What should I do here? Im really still a newbie in php and this my project final exam :(
Do I have to change the logout file code with the one you just gave me.???

Comment: Add to your logout script: session_unset(); session_destroy(); session_write_close(); setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/'); session_regenerate_id(true); and then redirect user to home page.

Comment: Here is the link:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/nehn95lflvrufbv/social_network.rar

Comment: Im still waiting please :(

Comment: i don't know. I tried your solution but still not working..
I just figured out that when I Empty all the data from the db table It always redirect the $_SESSION to the first user who shared an article..

Mind if you take a look at the script I provide you here?
Please, it's really urgent and don't have enough time to be done with this project... Just take a look at the index file and see If i made any error coz Im really stuck in with this problem and don't know what to do :(

Comment: remove ob_start, and change login_process.php:                 if($dbusername == $username && $dbpassword == $password){  $_SESSION['username'] = $username; header("Location: index.php"); exit; }

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate your patient with me.
but when I remove ob_start() it won't let me redirect the user to the home page, I just did what u said but still ..

Comment: Mind if you run the script in your localhost please?
Then, you'll see what's exactly the problem is.
Try to log in with a user (two users in the database table) and then logout and reloggin in using the other user... You'll figure out what is exactly the problem in this script

Comment: I updated login_process.php(http://pastebin.com/ekZJ63UB) and index.php (http://pastebin.com/9VTHzst4). Works as expected.

Comment: Oh! Thank you soo soo much ! Im gonna try and see and hopefully it work with me.. if it didn't work, Im gonna try the script in other computer coz this one Im very suspicious there is something wrong with the browser or something... Anyway, I'll try and gives you my feedback in a while... Thank you so much again for your help.. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! the updated code you gave me works well :) Thank you so much once again:)

Comment: Thank you Valery :)
I really appreciate your help and patient with newbies like "

Answer (score 1):

I agree with *@Valery Viktorovsky* but, 
Since `PHP 7` you cannot use `session_regenerate_id(true);` after you destroy the session...

the Changelog [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) Says :

```
7.0.0 - session_regenerate_id() saves old session data before closing.
```

**This one works in PHP 7 or later:**

```
ob_start();
session_start();
session_unset();
session_regenerate_id(true);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
header('LOCATION: index.php');
```

so you can try this out if you wan't to

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example:

```
//Delete all previous PHPSESSID cookies
$past = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10;
setcookie('PHPSESSID', false, time() - $past);
//Delete all the data in the $_SESSION
$_SESSION = array();
//Delete the old session file (true) and create a new session id
session_regenerate_id(true);
```