# PHP session not logging out / unset

Tags: php, session

I know this question has many duplicates, but I tried several of them and none of those have been answered.

Here is my code for logout.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require './codefiles/dbhelper.php';
    $dbh = new DbHelper();
    $dbh->Execute('UPDATE surveyors SET LoggedIn=\'0\', SessionID=\'\' WHERE Username=\''.$_SESSION['username'].'\'');
    session_unset();
    session_abort();
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION = array();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    unset($dbh);
    header('location:index.php');
?>
```

But the session variables are just too "stubborn" to be removed. Neither session values are being cleared not the session variables are being removed. Object **$dbh** is being unset but not **$_SESSION['username']**;

Another unrelated problem, despite I am setting the `LoggedIn = 0`, in my SQL query, it just stays as 1 in database. `LoggedIn` field is of type 'bit'. `SessionID` field is set to blank though.

Any solutions please?

EDIT:

Removed `echo $dbh->error` as it was unnecessary.

EDIT 2:

Added `session_destroy()` as suggested by *Hossam Magdy*.

Comment: have you tried `session_destroy();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php ?

Comment: Oh yes. I have.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Aborting a session seems like closing it, thus preventing writing to the storage. And I wonder what stopping you from using `session_set_save_handler()` with a class implementing `SessionHandlerInterface`?

Comment: @frz3993: I will give a shot to `session_set_save_handler()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the code for destroying the sessions was somehow not working in *logout.php*. It worked in *index.php* and other files, but will all sorts of unpredictable behavior.

Found a workaround to circumvent the problem. The **logout.php** has code as below:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logout'] = TRUE;
    header('location:index.php');
?>
```

And add this code to **index.php**:

```
# Implement logout functionality
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['logout']) && $_SESSION['logout'] == TRUE){
        foreach($_SESSION as $var => $value){
            unset($_SESSION[$var]);
        }
        session_destroy();
        session_unset();
    }
?>
```

It may not be a standardized solution, but the code works for me every time, with no unpredictable behavior.

Thanks everyone for sharing their ideas.

Comment: i guess foreach unset must be in logout.php or login.php before set new session values, in index.php does not work to me because i destroy a session what i need. Anyway it is a strange issue. Did you test this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759719/i-just-cant-destroy-a-session-in-php  ?

Comment: As I said, the my code worked in any file but not in my **logout.php** (don't know why). If it does not work for you, it may be because of our different logics. Any  ways, the link you suggested as solved my another problem, regenerating a new Session ID after every logout. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'codefiles/dbhelper.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
{
    header ("Location: login_form.php");
}
else
{
    session_destroy();
    die('You have been logged out.<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=login_form.php">');
}
?>
```

This is basically the "Logout" structure.

Comment: But `session_destroy()` is just not working, neither in logout.php nor in any other page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
session_start();
require './codefiles/dbhelper.php';
$dbh = new DbHelper();
$dbh->Execute('UPDATE surveyors SET LoggedIn=\'0\', SessionID=\'\' WHERE Username=\''.$_SESSION['username'].'\'');

echo session_status() . '<br />';

session_unset();    
session_destroy();

echo session_status();  

// header('location:index.php');
```

Let's see what session_status() says.
But on my projects unset && destroy work.

Comment: Though I am using session_start(), calling `session_destroy()` throws warning as: *Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxxxxx\index.php*. Regarding `echo session_status()`, it prints **1**.

Comment: Does session_status return 1 first time, second or both? According to http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-status.php 1 means no active session.

Comment: Calling `session_status()` before `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()` returns **2** and after, it returns **1**. And then calling `print_r($_SESSION);` prints all variables in the session.

Comment: Sorry, i tried on my own project. After unset & destroy     print_r($_SESSION); returns Array(). Really odd.

Comment: Please try my solution in your project and tell the result. Is it as expected?